# Implementing a method which is declared in an interface and parent class

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a little dilemma here,

say I have a class

```
public class Child extends Parent implements Interface{
 public static void main(String[] args){
  Child child = new Child();
   child.methodOne(); } }
```

where

```
abstract class Parent {

public void methodOne()  {
    System.out.print("cannot fly ");
}}

interface Interface {
public abstract void methodOne() throws Exception;}
```

There are no compilation errors with this structure

wherease if I did this

```
abstract class Parent {

public void methodOne() throws Exception {
    System.out.print("cannot fly ");
}}

interface Interface {
public abstract void methodOne(); }
```

Two compliation errors rise saying

```
Exception Exception in throws clause of Parent.methodOne() is not compatible with Interface.methodOne()
```

and

```
Unhandled exception type Exception
```

which asks to add `throws` or `try/catch` in `main` method

Why is that happening?

Comment: what happens if you add the throws clause in both places?

Comment: I think there are lot of explanation of what happens. In summary, you inherit a method from your `Parent` which partially match `Interface` signature. To solve the problem, just overrides the method and make it not throwing a checked exception. For example `try { super.methodOne(); } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you implement an interface (or override a method from a parent class, same thing), you need to respect the contract of that interface. Respecting the contract means that you cannot throw more exceptions than in the interface declaration.

In both cases, `Interface` is the contract, and `Parent` is the implementation (via the "binding" between the two that happens in class `Child`).

In the first case, the interface says that `methodOne()` is *allowed* to throw Exception, but does not have to. Your actual implementation in `Parent` does not throw anything, so it is a subset of the contract and is fine.

In the second case, the interface says that `methodOne()` will not throw anything (*), hence any implementation consequently is not allowed to throw any exception. However, the implementation in `Parent` asks to be allowed to throw, which is incompatible with the interface contract; hence the compiler error.

Also note in this second case that you could very well override `methodOne()` in `Child` with an empty `throws` declaration so that the signature would conform to the interface contract. You could then call `super.methodOne()` and rewrap `Exception` as `RuntimeException` (for example).

By the way:

- if you implement multiple interfaces with the same method signatures, the implementation can throw only the intersection of `throws` declaration of all interfaces;
- you don't need to use the `abstract` keyword in interfaces, because method declarations in interface are always abstract by nature.

---

(*) except for RuntimeException's of course.

Comment: Thank you that was pretty helpful.

Answer (score 3):

When you are doing this,

```
public class Child  extends Parent implements Interface
```

- Parent class is implementing the Interface.
- methodOne in Parent class becomes the overridden method.
- Child which is extending Parent class, don't see this exception.

But, when you are explicitly throwing an `exception` in the Parent `class`' method, you have to handle that exception when you make a call from the child object.

Answer (score 1):

The `throws` declaration is not part of the `methodOne()` contract in the interface `Interface`.

Whenever you implement an interface you must implement your method contracts, you can do this without adding the `throws` declaration if the interface has a `throws` declaration.

However you cannot *add* functionality that isn't stated in the `Interface` contract.

You can fix the other error by modifying your `main` method to also throw an `Exception`:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Child child = new Child();
   child.methodOne(); 
 }
```

or by surrounding the `methodOne()` call in a `try-catch` block:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Child child = new Child();
   try{
       child.methodOne(); 
   }catch(Exception e){
      //do something to handle exception i.e. System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   }
 }
```

Additional reading: [Java interface throws an exception but interface implementation does not throw an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607060/java-interface-throw-an-exception-but-interface-implementation-does-not-throw-an)

Excerpt:

> A general rule of implementing and extending is you can make your new class or interface "less restrictive" but not "more restrictive". If you think of the requirement to handle an exception as a restriction, an implementation that doesn't declare the exception is less restrictive. Anybody who codes to the interface will not have trouble with your class.

Comment: i dont understand. why does it work for him in the first instance?

Comment: oh wait, is it because the method is a part of the class first. so from now on, whoever wants to use that method must follow the contract set by the class. members can add to the contract but cant take away from it.

Comment: @AbtPst you almost have the concept, just a bit mixed up. Members can choose not to include things like throws declarations, but they can't add declarations that aren't declared in the interface. No member explicitly modifies the interface.