# Why can class implements two interfaces with generic method?

Tags: java, generics, interface, implementation

There are 2 interfaces:

```
public interface A {
    ArrayList<Integer> all() throws ExceptionA;
}

public interface B {
    List<String> all() throws ExceptionB;
}
```

And there is class that implements them:

```
public class C implements A, B {
    @Override
    public ArrayList all() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Also checked exceptions:

```
public class ExceptionA extends Exception {
}


public class ExceptionB extends Exception {
}
```

When I compile this code everything is OK. Why?

I know that in implementation we can use subtype (in this situation ArrayList is subtype of List). But I have next questions:

1. Why in implementation you can omit *throws* part? In interface methods there are *throws* parts of checked exceptions
2. Why in implementation you can omit generic type?

Comment: 1. [Java interface throws an exception but interface implementation does not throw an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607060/java-interface-throws-an-exception-but-interface-implementation-does-not-throw-a)

Comment: 2. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/3788176 you can, but you shouldn't.

Comment: 2. because of backwards compatibility