# StringBuilder.append(CharSequence) with no IOException?

Tags: java, exception, stringbuilder

I note that `StringBuilder` indirectly implements `Appendable`.

`Appendable.append(CharSequence)` throws the checked exception `IOException`. So how does `AbstractStringBuilder.append(CharSequence)` get away with not declaring `IOException`? Consequently, how is it that I never have to worry about `IOException` when I append to a `StringBuilder`?

Is this some odd exception just for existing classes that have been retrofitted for `Appendable`, or am I forgetting part of my basic Java rules?

Comment: Subclasses can indeed get away with throwing different exception: they can either declare not throwing any, or they can declare to throw a subclass of exception declared by their superclass.

Comment: I believe a very similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607060/java-interface-throws-an-exception-but-interface-implementation-does-not-throw-a). Please check it out!

Comment: I think it is the opposite, the method in `AbstractStringBulder` can throw *at most* an `IOException` or lower (more specific, subclass of `IOException`). The [JLS 8.4.8.3. Requirements in Overriding and Hiding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3) for that:"*... a method declaration m2 in B overrides or hides a method declaration m1 in A. Then:
    **If m2 has a throws clause that mentions any checked exception types, then m1 must have a throws clause, or a compile-time error occurs**...*"

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger, the next passage is a lot more relevant: *For every checked exception type listed in the throws clause of `m2`, that same exception class or one of its supertypes must occur in the erasure (§4.6) of the throws clause of `m1`. Otherwise a compile-time error occurs.*

Comment: and "*... **never** have to worry about IOException...*" is wrong, if you cast to `Appendable` you will have to

Comment: @M.Prokhorov there is no throws clause of *m2*... so hard to say which one is more relevant - probably both together

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger, well, yes whole JLS is equally important. People are focused hard on fact that implementor could not have any `throws` declared, that I feel they might miss that if they both do, then implementor might throw more same or more specific exceptions, is my point.

Answer (score 0):

When implementing an interface you may not throw an exception, so you can the following:

```
new Appendable() {

    @Override
    public Appendable append(CharSequence charSequence) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Appendable append(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Appendable append(char c) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can throw a subclass of exception declared by your superclass/interface.

Answer (score 0):

When implementing an interface or extending an abstract class,
you can decide whether to throw an exception or not.

An overriding method can throw any unchecked exceptions, regardless of whether the overridden method throws exceptions or not. However, the overriding method should not throw checked exceptions that are new or broader than the ones declared by the overridden method.